# Heating ramp plot, increasing and decreasing axis

Tags: pgfplots

First of let me make clear I don't know how to properly name this in English, so feel free to edit the title or leave a comment.

I need to plot this data in a way that heating and cooling (Tr) shows on the same axis and **same direction**. See picture.
I could not find a way to make the x-axis go to 900 and then decrease back, while still going from left to right.

I can only get the desired result if I plot by the time (t), however, I need an axis showing the temperature.

I have tried breaking into two plots and having it mirrored but that would take me too much time with other plots like this in the future. Aside from been not too elegant and the visual is far from good in the case of a complicated curve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

    % UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction, abbreviations}

    % GRAPHICS
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,height=6cm,compat=newest}

% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset{select coords between index/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
            \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        }
}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{datax.dat}
t,HF,Gewicht,Normal,DTG,Tr
574,1.20838,8.47718,0.981320918,-0.00509898,67.8333
3794,27.9521,2.06633,0.239198985,-0.009580838,372.333
6944,6.17274,0.420004,0.04861979,0,897.333
6964,3.65761,0.419016,0.048505419,0,900 
7424,-19.0714,0.413001,0.047809121,0,900
13984,-28.3111,0.367016,0.0424858830,900    
15194,-4.02426,0.321001,0.037159173,0,727.667
17074,28.3149,0.190241,0.022022356,0,414.333
18914,13.0023,-0.164632,-0.01905785,0,107.667
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bigskip

\pgfplotsset{
scale only axis,
minor x tick num=3,
}

\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
ymin=-0.1, ymax=1.1,
minor y tick num=4,
xlabel=Time (\si{\second}),
%xlabel=Temperature (\si{\degreeCelsius}),
ylabel=\ref{TGA} Mass ($\%$),
,
]
\addplot [smooth,thick,cyan,] table [,x=t, y=Normal, col sep=comma] {datax.dat};
\label{TGA}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=right,
minor y tick num=4,
ylabel=\ref{DTG} Derivative Mass ($\% /\ \si{\degreeCelsius}$),
]
\addplot [smooth,thick,dashed,green!60!black,] table [x=t, y=HF, col sep=comma] {datax.dat};
\label{DTG};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the question. In the data, `Tr` first increases and then decreases as a function of `t`. So your plots already accomplish what you want to achieve, don't they? Could you perhaps add a sketch of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger'scat , I hope its more clear now, edited the image. I need the X axis to go from 100 to 900 and back to 100, according to the data loaded.

Comment: So you want to change the labels that show the time t to labels that show the temperature at this time, or do you (also) want to change the plots?

Comment: Both things would work, I guess showing the temperature label would be easier.

Comment: The row starting with `13984` only has 5 elements. This causes actually some problems. Please consider adding an element such that the temperature is defined in this row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds the temperature as a function of the time on the upper x axis. Since the temperatures are not equidistant, some ticks are suppressed since they would overlap otherwise. The minimal distance is encoded in

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\itest}{ifthenelse(abs(\Time/10000-\LastTime/10000)>0.1,1,0)}%
```

Please note also that the row starting with `13984` in your data file only has 5 elements. I added an element. When you run this code, make sure that you really overwrite the data file, with your original data set you will get an `unbalanced columns` error.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

    % UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction, abbreviations}

    % GRAPHICS
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,height=6cm,compat=newest}

% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset{select coords between index/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
            \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        }
}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{datax.dat}
t,HF,Gewicht,Normal,DTG,Tr
574,1.20838,8.47718,0.981320918,-0.00509898,67.8333
3794,27.9521,2.06633,0.239198985,-0.009580838,372.333
6944,6.17274,0.420004,0.04861979,0,897.333
6964,3.65761,0.419016,0.048505419,0,900 
7424,-19.0714,0.413001,0.047809121,0,900
13984,-28.3111,0.367016,0.0424858830,0,900    
15194,-4.02426,0.321001,0.037159173,0,727.667
17074,28.3149,0.190241,0.022022356,0,414.333
18914,13.0023,-0.164632,-0.01905785,0,107.667
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\def\pgfmathtruncatemacroFPU#1#2{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}%

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize%<- am not sure about this one
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[header=true,col sep=comma]{datax.dat}{\datatable}%   
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \iloop in {0,...,\the\numexpr\numrows-1}
{\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\iloop}{0}{\Time}%
 \ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\iloop}{5}{\Temp}%
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Temp}{\Temp}%
 \ifnum\iloop=0
  \edef\LstTimes{\Time}
  \edef\LstTemps{\Temp}
  \edef\LastTime{\Time}
 \else
  \pgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\itest}{ifthenelse(abs(\Time/10000-\LastTime/10000)>0.1,1,0)}%
  \ifnum\itest=1
   \edef\LstTimes{\LstTimes,\Time}
   \edef\LstTemps{\LstTemps,\Temp}
   \edef\LastTime{\Time}
  \fi
 \fi}
 %\pgfmathsetmacro{\LstTemps}{{\LstTemps}[0]}
% \show\LstTemps
 %\typeout{\LstTimes,\LstTemps}

\pgfplotsset{
scale only axis,
minor x tick num=3,
}

\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
ymin=-0.1, ymax=1.1,
minor y tick num=4,
xlabel=Time (\si{\second}),
ylabel=\ref{TGA} Mass ($\%$),
,
]
\addplot [smooth,thick,cyan,] table [,x=t, y=Normal, col sep=comma] {datax.dat};
\label{TGA}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=right,
minor y tick num=4,
axis x line*=right,scaled ticks = false,
xlabel={Temperature (\si{\degreeCelsius})},
xtick=\LstTimes,xticklabels/.expanded=\LstTemps,
%xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision = 0},
ylabel=\ref{DTG} Derivative Mass ($\% /\ \si{\degreeCelsius}$),
]
\addplot [smooth,thick,dashed,green!60!black,] table [x=t, y=HF, col sep=comma] {datax.dat};
\label{DTG};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, I do however get lots of overlap, or too few ticks. 
Would you mind explaining a bit more about how to tune the `\Time/10000-\LastTime/10000` ?

Comment: @G.Bay `\pgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\itest}{ifthenelse(abs(\Time/10000-\LastTime/10000)>0.1,1,0)` checks the time difference between the last time when it put a temperature and the current time. If the condition, `abs(\Time/10000-\LastTime/10000)>0.1` in this case, is fulfilled it will place a new tick. If you want to get less ticks, you need to replace `0.1` by a larger number, if you want to get more by a smaller number.